# Pickerview crash

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I want to get 2 values from a UIPickerView and merge them in one string. I can fetch them correctly, but the merging in the last NSString keeps crashing with sigabrt when I try to NSLog it.

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
UIPickerView *pickerView = (UIPickerView *)[actionSheet viewWithTag:101];

NSLog(@"Time:: %@%@",[dataArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]],[minArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]]);  
NSString *hour = [dataArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
NSLog(@"%@", hour);
NSString *minute = [minArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]];
NSLog(@"%@", minute);

NSString *totalTime = [totalTime stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@", hour, minute];
NSLog(@"%@", totalTime);
//[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `totalTime` in declaration is used in its own initializer. Change this line:

```
NSString *totalTime = [totalTime stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@", hour, minute];
```

to this line:

```
NSString *totalTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", hour, minute];
```

Comment: How could I miss that.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *totalTime = [hour stringByAppendingString:minute];
```

will be a simple solution.